# Extracting Object from Some() and Using it

Tags: scala

In the below code, `encoded` is a JSON string. The `JSON.parseFull()` function is returning an object of the form: `Some(Map(...))`. I am using `.get` to extract the `Map`, but am unable to index it as the compiler sees it as type `Any`. Is there any to provide the compiler visibility that it is, in fact, a map?

```
val parsed = JSON.parseFull(encoded)
val mapped = parsed.get
```

Comment: val mapped: Map[...] = parsed.get do anything? (you need to fill in the ... with the type you expect)

Comment: The Map is of form `Map[String, Any]` where Any is either a list or a string itself. Calling `val mapped: Map[String, Any] = parsed.get` throws a type mismatch between `Any` and `Map[String, Any]`. I'm assuming this is because before the `.get` is called, the contents of `Some()` are though of as `Any()`.

Comment: what is `JSON.parseFull`?  Is there anyway to tell your json parser what types you are expecting?  Is sounds like the problem is that method is just returning `Option[Any]`.

Comment: Just the JSON parser from `import scala.util.parsing.json._`.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `collect` with pattern matching to match on the type:

```
scala> val parsed: Option[Any] = Some(Map("1" -> List("1")))
parsed: Option[Any] = Some(Map(1 -> List(1)))
scala> val mapped = parsed.collect{
  case map: Map[String, Any] => map
}
mapped: Option[Map[String,Any]] = Some(Map(1 -> List(1)))
```

You can do something like the following in the case of a `List` value to get values from the `List`:

```
scala> mapped.get.map{ case(k, List(item1)) => item1}
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Any] = List(1)
```

Comment: The exact solution above threw the following error: `Error:(40, 50) type mismatch; found   : Option[Map[String,Any]] required: Map[String,Any] val mapped: Map[String, Any] = parsed.collect{`, but was very close to what I ended up doing to get it working. Thanks for your help! I'll post my solution when I am able, but basically I just used `get` and pattern matching identical to what you did above.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use a combination of the `get` function and pattern matching similar to what was posted in Tanjin's response to get the desired result.

```
object ReadFHIR {

  def fatal(msg: String) = throw new Exception(msg)

  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fc = new FhirContext()
    val client = fc.newRestfulGenericClient("http://test.fhir.org/r2")
    val bundle = client.search().forResource("Observation")
      .prettyPrint()
      .execute()

    val jsonParser = fc.newJsonParser()
    val encoded = jsonParser.encodeBundleToString(bundle)
    val parsed = JSON.parseFull(encoded)

    val mapped: Map[String, Any] = parsed.get match{
      case map: Map[String, Any] => map
    }

    println(mapped("resourceType"))
  }

}
```